# Anypoint Studio Logger: pretty print JSON payload

Tags: json, logging, mule, pretty-print

Testing a POC and wondering what the quickest/simplest way to pretty print a JSON payload in the Anypoint Studio console.  I'd rather not figure out how to use a [Groovy component](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXWWISA4/implement-pretty-print-in-mulesoft) to accomplish this.

I've tried setting the application/json `indent` property to true as below, but it still prints the entire object on a single line (which is indented).

```
output application/json indent=true
```

Any lightweight solutions for quick POC work?

Comment: What exactly are you doing to log? Please share your flow as XML.

Answer (score 0):

The console in Studio shows what it is being logged. If you are using DataWeave to create the JSON, as evidenced by the script you shared, then the default value for the [indent writer property is true](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-formats#writer-properties-for-json). So when logging it, the generated JSON will be pretty-printed by default.

Example:

```
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" >
        <ee:message >
            <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    a:"aaaa",
    b: {c:1, d:"dddd"},
    e: "ccc"
}]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Payload: #[payload]"/>
```

Output (omitting all the logging information for clarity):

```
Payload: {
  "a": "aaaa",
  "b": {
    "c": 1,
    "d": "dddd"
  },
  "e": "ccc"
}
```